# Python Django: models in root giving error

Tags: python, django-models

Iam newbie to Python and Django. I have following "models.py" file .

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Greeting(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
  content = models.TextField()
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

1- When I run following command:

```
from models import Greeting
```

It gives following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But when i run above

```
from guestbook.models import Greeting
```

it gives no error.

Can some one guide me how can I run "models.py" file (without any error), which exists in root folder(not in "guestbook" application folder)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you create a seperate folder (application) and put your models.py and other files into that? Also, you can not import your model from `models` it keeps basic structural information and functions of models, not your model itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't.  You are fighting the basic project/application model of Django which underlies the entire system. You will continue to have nothing but problems and issues if you continue down this path.

Create an application and put the models.py in that application's subdirectory.

Edit: I don't mean to sound too harsh but one of the most important things I've learned about Django and Rails is "Don't fight the system".